# reset git branch to earlier checkout

Tags: git

I've reverted my local branch in git to an earlier version with this command:

```
git reset --hard ab5a3914c73
```

How can I get that version to be the current version of my git branch? I want to overwrite all previous commits with this version.

Comment: It already is. That's how you do it.

Comment: Do you mean on the remote? Force-push your local branch to the remote repository. Be aware that this can cause problems if other developers have already checked out the "old" version (before the reset)

Comment: It sounds like you have moved your local branch where you want, as @jthill mentioned.  Are you asking how to update the remote branch to drop commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to update the remote branch, you would need to force push, `git push -f`.  If you are working with a team, it should be a coordinated effort.  Also, depending on your server-side settings, force pushing to a branch may be restricted.

See: [Git Push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)